# Adding dot line after section name in letterpaper

Tags: section-titles

A question about how to add dot line in letterpaper class.

My target is to create a section title like
[image]

I try to use

```
\titleformat{\section}{
 \vspace{-4pt}\scshape\raggedright\bfseries\large  \color{cyan} 
}{}{}{\titlerule*[.5pc]{.}}
```

but only resulting in
[image]

where the dot line appear in front of the section name.

Is there anyway I can move it to behind section name?